# Liquibase intellij integration?

Tags: intellij-idea, liquibase

According to the liquibase website, there is an intellij IDEA plugin available in the plugin store, but I cannot seem to find it.  Is the plugin discontinued?  Is there some alternative for liquibase integrations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Liquibase Intellij plugin has been discontinued. I'll update the website to remove the reference.

Comment: I asked a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33484761/3680045   I looked all over SO and the forum but couldn't find the solution, would you please have a look and give some advise? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why was it discontinued?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is the same plugin you are looking for but there is *Liquibase EJB integration* plugin in IntelliJ repositories. You can find it under *Settings/Plugins/Browse Repositories*. It is also available [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3698?pr=). Last version is 3 years old though, so it's likely that it's no longer maintained.

Here is its description:

> LiquiBase EJB Integration Plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA. Compares LiquiBase Database ChangeLog with EJB entity model providing inspections and intentions adding to ChangeLog.

Comment: That seems to be for EJB which I'm not using.

Comment: @JeremySalwen According to the plugin description it _Works for any module with JPA facet._. So it should work for instance with Spring/Hibernate project without EJB. But if you don't use JPA as such then it's probably of no use. There doesn't seem to be any other Liquibase IntelliJ plugin.