# DDL command not created by liquibase when trying to run it from Java code

Tags: java, liquibase

Update:

I think the problem is this line because it returns an empty list when I called `changelog.getChangeSets()`, so what is wrong this code?

```
    static liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog changelog = new DatabaseChangeLog(
            "src/main/resources/changelog.xml");
```

Original post:

My goal is to run database DDL commands with existing changelog in Java class. 
Currently my set up is like this:

```
public class LiquibaseWithJavaCode {
    //find the location of the existing changelog.xml file
    static liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog changelog = new DatabaseChangeLog(
            "src/main/resources/changelog.xml");

    static void executeUpdate1() throws SQLException, LiquibaseException {

        java.sql.Connection connection = getConnection();

        Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance()
                .findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(
                        new JdbcConnection(connection));

        Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(changelog,
                new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);

        liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

        Connection conn = null;
        Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
        connectionProps.put("user", "liquibase");
        connectionProps.put("password", "password");

        conn = DriverManager
                .getConnection(
                        "jdbc:sqlserver://111.11.1.1;databaseName=liquibase;SelectMethod=cursor",
                        connectionProps);
        return conn;
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException,
        LiquibaseException {
            executeUpdate1();
    }
```

When I run it here is the output:
[image]

I created the `changelog.xml` and it contains a lot of changeset that handles a lot of DDL command. But it seems the `changeLogFile` does not contain any changeset, it is empty. I double checked with the database, and it was indeed no actually table created, only two tables `DATABASECHANGELOG` and `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK` being created.

Did I do anything wrong? How do I correct it? To be honest I am not familiar about it so please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

new DatabaseChangeLog just creates an new empty changelog file. To parse an existing file, use:

```
ChangeLogParser parser = ChangeLogParserFactory.getInstance().getParser("src/main/resources/changelog.xml", resourceAccessor);
DatabaseChangeLog databaseChangeLog = parser.parse("src/main/resources/changelog.xml", new ChangeLogParameters(), resourceAccessor);
```

For a resourceAccessor, you probably want `new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried to run it, and it looks I am getting `liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException` at the `parser.parse("src/main/resources/changelog.xml", new ChangeLogParameters(), resourceAccessor);` line. I have tried to use absolute path from windows also, but still getting this exception. Did I miss something? Or is there anything to do with the version of Liquibase I am runnning?

Comment: The more specific reason of this exception is "src/main/resources/changelog.xml does not exist"

Comment: The ResourceAccessor is what is used to look up the changelog, including the path. If you are using ClassLoaderResourceAccessor, the path should be more like just "changelog.xml" since src/main/resources will end up as a classpath root. If you want to (or need to) use the full /src/main/resources/changelog.xml, you'll probably need to use FileSystemResourceAccessor instead